# WebSocket server not working for some reasons

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I tried to create a very simple server using ws,
When i run the server `node index.js` and i lunch `localhost:8080` in my browser nothing appear in my console.

i should see `client connected on localhost:8080` printed to the console

-index.js

```
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});
const onConnect = wss => console.log('client connected on localhost:8080');

Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(wss, 'connection')
  .subscribe(onConnect);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect to WebSocket by open it directly in a browser. You should create HTTP server and response with some HTML page. In this HTML page you should include javascript that connects to your WebSocket server:

```
<script>
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't see that in their documentation, my bad.
Thank you :D

Comment: @Focus you are welcome! do not forget to mark this answer as correct if it helps, please :)